# GROUP BY aggregate needed when using window function in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, sum, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I need a table with sum of GP for every product and month as well as the running sum of GP for the product since ever. Although I already found a walkaroud for this, this really confuses me and I would appreciate a hint here.

In redshift, when I try to use window SUM like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "tmp.gp_sum" AS (
SELECT 
"productID",
"month",
SUM("gp") AS "gp_sum",
SUM("gp") OVER (PARTITION BY p."productID" ORDER BY "month" ROWS unbounded preceding) as "gp_runsum" 
FROM "products" 
GROUP BY "productID", "month"
);
```

DB returns an error saying "gp" needs to be in the GROUP BY statement, but that doesn't work for me. The only walkaroud i had found was to nest another aggregate function, which seems to work fine - at least in this case:

```
SUM(SUM("gp")) OVER (PARTITION BY p."productID" ORDER BY "month" ROWS
```

Cound anyone explain this please?

Thanks, Thomas

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT "productID", "month", SUM("gp") AS "gp_sum"
FROM "products" 
GROUP BY "productID", "month"
```

This does `SUM` over `productID` and `month`. Your window function calculates `SUM` over `productID`. SQL still needs "a rule" how to calculate `gp_runsum` by `productID` and `month` (group by).

Your solution (`SUM(SUM(...))`) should work, but you can always calculate running sum in separate sql and then join on `productID`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE "tmp.gp_sum" AS
(
    SELECT   "productID",
             "month",
              SUM("gp") AS "gp_sum",
              SUM("gp") OVER (PARTITION BY p."productID" ORDER BY "month" ROWS unbounded preceding) as "gp_runsum" 
    FROM     "products" 
    GROUP BY "productID", "month", "gp"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE "tmp.gp_sum" AS (
    SELECT 
        "productID",
        "month",
        SUM("gp") OVER (PARTITION BY "productID", "month") AS "gp_sum",
        SUM("gp") OVER (PARTITION BY p."productID" ORDER BY "month" ROWS unbounded preceding) 
        as "gp_runsum" 
    FROM "products" 
);
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation?